# How to get profile Headline of users linkedin account by api in php

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using v2 api and trying to access the headline info by login as linkedin api process. I got success to access firstName, lastName, profilePicture but not getting Headline. So How can I get Headline info?

I'm using below code for this

```
 if(isset($_GET['code']) && json_decode($server_output)->access_token != ''){

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,headLine,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=".json_decode($server_output)->access_token);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $server_output2 = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);

 $user_data = json_decode($server_output2);

 print_r($user_data);
```

}

Comment: double check your app have the `r_basicprofile ` permission. As described [here in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Your App should have the `r_basicprofile` permission to retrieve the headline of the user and you should request this scope during OAuth flow with the user in order to retrieve a valid token for the scope.

See the doc  of  Retrieve Current Member's Profile [Permission section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#permissions):

> ***r_basicprofile***   Required to retrieve name, photo, headline, and vanity name for the authenticated user. Please review [Basic Profile
> Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile). Note that the v2 r_basicprofile permission grants only a
> subset of fields provided in v1.